# Sonata Admin translation does not translate translation array

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I am having a translation array in Sonata Admin that looks like this:

> messages.en.yml

```
admin:
    form:
        label:
            identifier:
                identificationTitle: Some text here
                otherKey: blabla
```

when I am trying to access it like this

```
{{ 'admin.form.label.identifier.identificationTitle'|trans }}
```

or like this

```
{{ 'admin.form.label.identifier.identificationTitle'|trans({}, 'MyBundle') }}
```

they don't work and I get as a response the key string.

But if I use it like this:

> messages.en.yml

```
admin_form_label_identifier_identificationTitle: some text here
```

> the view

```
{{ 'admin_form_label_identifier_identificationTitle'|trans }}
```

it works.

Obviously I don't want to have this format but use the nice array formatted option. 
Is this even possible in Sonata Admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suposse that somewhere in your project there is translation for 
admin.form.label.

When you define the same key as value and also as array, only one of translation work. Eg:

```
 admin: translation for admin
 admin:
    form:  translation for admin.form
```